# Combining 2 logic SQL statements in 1 query

Tags: mysql, sql

My question is: How to combine 2 logical statements into 1 SQL query. They both have to be true individually but something true in one statement doesn't have to be in the other, for example the meta_value being greater should only be true when I'm asking for the beginning of a course, and vice versa.
This is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT course_id FROM `wp_database`
WHERE (meta_key = 'begin' AND meta_value > 1604185200)
AND (meta_key = 'end' AND meta_value < 1619372800)
```

This is my database structure:

```
meta_id | course_id | meta_key | meta_value
-------------------------------------------
 1      | 1         | name     | Test1
 2      | 1         | begin    | 1604230000
 3      | 1         | end      | 1604270000
 4      | 2         | name     | Test2
 5      | 2         | begin    | 1623372800
 6      | 2         | end      | 1623385800
```

At the moment I don't receive any output.

Comment: A meta_key can never be begin and end at the same time. Do you simply want `OR` instead of `AND`?

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also specify its expected result.

Comment: The result should be the course id within the time frame that I specify, so in the example case the course id 1. I've tried Gordon's answer and that seems to be working.

Comment: @jarlh just to understand, so my idea didn't work because the brackets don't separate the individual statements? Because I thought it would work that first bracket = TRUE and second bracket = TRUE and then I can combine those two TRUE with the middle AND.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want aggregation and `having` to combine multiple rows into a single row for the result set:

```
SELECT course_id
FROM `wp_database`
GROUP BY course_id
HAVING MAX(meta_key = 'begin' AND meta_value > 1604185200) > 0 AND
       MAX(meta_key = 'end' AND meta_value < 1619372800) > 0;
```

The `HAVING` clause is checking if the conditions exist for some row in the group.

Comment: @DrWho_Nr13  if this answer is solved your problem then please mark green tick as an accepted answer for future readers.

Comment: @KUMAR yeah I'd like to, but it hasn't let me yet, I still have to wait a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You need `UNION` operator. Try like:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT course_id FROM `wp_database`
WHERE (meta_key = 'begin' AND meta_value > 1604185200) )
UNION    
(SELECT DISTINCT course_id FROM `wp_database` WHERE (meta_key = 'end' AND meta_value < 1619372800) )
```

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT here, UNION returns no duplicates.